# python to_string not showing entire string

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe

```
id     url
1      https://alengthyname.alengthdomainname.com/example1/example2
2      https://alengthyname1.alengthdomainname.com/example1/example2
```

I'm trying the get the urls and convert it to plain text

```
urls = df['url'].to_string(index=False)
print(urls)
```

I'm getting

```
>https://alengthyname.alengthdomainname.com/...
 https://alengthyname1.alengthdomainname.com/...
```

May I know why urls is storing compressed `/...` value, but not full value? And how to assign the full value to `urls`.

Comment: `for r in df.itertuples(): print(r.url)`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel You should not iterate over a dataframe with a `for` loop, certainly not just to print it.

Comment: @HenryEcker, I just dont want to display the complete value, I just to assign the full value to `urls` variable.

Comment: `urls = '\n'.join(df['url'])`?

Comment: @astroboy1 it is storing the full value of your variable, it isn't printing the full variable though, to save console space. you can see this if you print the values as values

Comment: @DeepSpace, my point was just to show the OP that the full value is there if he needs it.

Answer (score 4):

the configuration is picked from `display.max_colwidth`. You can change the configuration using following command :

```
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 10000)
```

Comment: I just dont want to display the complete value, I just to assign the full value to urls variable.

Comment: Need this `df['url'].to_list()` ?? @astroboy1

Comment: I think it more of pandas behaviour. You can read more about it here :https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9784

Comment: @RajatMishra, Yes it is a pandas behavior of displaying. But in my case, the variable is storing the `/...` value. @HenryEcker's hack got me the solution. Thanks anyways.

Comment: There is no hack... the data frame is storing the entire variable. It's just shortening it for display! @astroboy1

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP and can confirm that it is NOT storing the entire string in the variable (at least in my case). I printed the string to disk and opened up the file and we still have the ellipsis. This is unexpected and undesirable behavior that can be fixed via modifying Pandas display options. Ugh.